# Wordpress Visual Composer editor fails in a three level container/components

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been creating VC components for a while, but I have a weird ajax problem when trying to edit a custom element located inside two nested custom containers.

The code tries to do the following:

- Creates a main container named "Your gallery" with some fields
- Creates a child container named "Gallery Image" with some fields and "Your gallery" as parent
- Finally creates a child component named "Gallery Image Text" with some fields and "Gallery Image" as parent

These entities are just an example, not our real entities, but the code and logic is the same.

When using Visual Composer we can add gallery, images and text containers/elements without problems, also we can edit the fields in the first container level (Gallery), and in the second level (Image), but when we try to edit the fields in the third level (Image Text) we don't see the fields of the third level, instead we see the fields of the upper (second) level.

In brief when we try to edit the fields of the component of the third level we see the fields of the second while using Visual Composer in WP.

The problem looks like this on the interface:

[image]

Looks like the ajax of the third level is failing, and it ends calling the ajax of the second one... does anyone have experience developing nested VC components?

We also tried with a clean installation of WP using twentysixteen theme without any other plug installed.

Our code:

```
function the_gallery() {

    //Register "container" content element. It will hold all your inner (child) content elements
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Your Gallery", "my-text-domain"),
        "base" => "your_gallery",
        "as_parent" => array('only' => 'single_img'), // Use only|except attributes to limit child shortcodes (separate multiple values with comma)
        "content_element" => true,
        "show_settings_on_create" => false,
        "is_container" => true,
        "params" => array(
            // add params same as with any other content element
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "heading" => __("Level 1", "my-text-domain"),
                "param_name" => "level_1",
                "description" => __("If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.", "my-text-domain")
            )
        ),
        "js_view" => 'VcColumnView'
    ) );
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Gallery Image", "my-text-domain"),
        "base" => "single_img",
        "content_element" => true,
        "as_parent" => array('only' => 'single_text'), // Use only|except attributes to limit child shortcodes (separate multiple values with comma)
        "as_child" => array('only' => 'your_gallery'), // Use only|except attributes to limit parent (separate multiple values with comma)
        "params" => array(
            // add params same as with any other content element
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "heading" => __("Level 2", "my-text-domain"),
                "param_name" => "level_2",
                "description" => __("If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.", "my-text-domain")
            )
        )
    ) );
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __("Gallery Image Text", "my-text-domain"),
        "base" => "single_text",
        "content_element" => true,
        "as_child" => array('only' => 'single_img'), // Use only|except attributes to limit parent (separate multiple values with comma)
        "params" => array(
            // add params same as with any other content element
            array(
                "type" => "textfield",
                "heading" => __("Level 3", "my-text-domain"),
                "param_name" => "level_3",
                "description" => __("If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.", "my-text-domain")
            )
        )
    ) );
    //Your "container" content element should extend WPBakeryShortCodesContainer class to inherit all required functionality
    if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
        class WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {
        }
    }
    if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
        class WPBakeryShortCode_Single_Img extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {
        }
    }
    if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCode' ) ) {
        class WPBakeryShortCode_Single_Text extends WPBakeryShortCode {
        }
    }
}

add_action('vc_before_init', 'the_gallery');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official response from VC support is:

> I think the issue is because your are using a third level nesting
>   which is not tested and is most likely not supported by our plugin.

We made a small patch for this in the backend.min.js basically the solution is to avoid calling the upper levels using a cookie for a few seconds (yes its nasty, but it works):

```
editElement: function(e) {

    if (!getCookie("vc_bug_fix_flag")) {
        createCookie("vc_bug_fix_flag", true); // it creates the cookie for some seconds

        _.isObject(e) && e.preventDefault(), (!vc.active_panel || !vc.active_panel.model || !this.model || vc.active_panel.model && this.model && vc.active_panel.model.get("id") != this.model.get("id")) && (vc.closeActivePanel(), vc.edit_element_block_view.render(this.model));

        }
    },
```

Comment: where does this go in the backend.min.js file? I really need a solution for this that can be shipped with the theme.